# In run-it-twice which scenario is more profitable?

Tags: poker-strategy, pot-limit

let's say in 6 card plo cash game you have nuts on the flop with big pot in the center with more than 2 players for show down. Now you can go all-in in 2 ways -

1. In the flop itself. (we see 2 extra cards in turn and river)
2. In the turn after checking the flop. (we see only 1 extra card in river)

which scenario is more profitable in the long run ? is there any calculation we can make?

Comment: I believe running it more than once doesn't actually effect your expected return/profitability, but rather it only affects the variance of the situation. I may be wrong on that one as I've not really given it much depth in terms of breaking it down. Your profitability would be more based on your equities rather.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in profitability running it once or twice assuming that both of your opponents will call when you go all in, it will only increase your variance i.e. reducing the impact of a cooler on your session if your hand can possibly be outdrawn.

More importantly, I would think about the best way to get value from your opponents. For example, if you have the nut flush on an all spade flop, you should evaluate the best play to try and get your opponents to put chips in the pot. going all in might scare them off

Answer (score 1):

As long as your nuts are unbeatable, both scenarios are equally profitable. If some of the remaining players can still make a better hand, then it depends on the odds of that happening.

In principle, you want to put as much money in the pot as you can while you're still ahead, but that is of course not always possible. Factors like position, the board texture, aggressiveness of your opponents and so on may force you to act one way or another.